# Button click event not fired in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please tell me why button click event not fire in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bR4b4/)?

I want to make stoppropagation and preventdefault, but I am stuck .

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        alert("button");
    }); 
});
```

Comment: It does fire. I don't know what's the problem here

Comment: best place to start is the docs  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: It's working fine. Maybe you have blocked alerts in your browser..?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's working just fine

Comment: how to enable on browser

Comment: On my browser it is not working..

Comment: @user2648752 check what error console is giving(F12),might be you missed out jquery plugins

Comment: Maybe you have disable the JS. Enable it.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Instead of alert, try console.log() and see. I had similar issue previously.

Comment: what is the use of preventdefualt .I found the good example of stoppropagation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#btn").click(function(){
                    alert("button");
                }); 
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <button id="btn">test</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is use of preventdefualt in jquerry

Comment: the default action of the event will not be triggered 
http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/
anchor tag, submit button, dropdown having default actions, we can prevent that(Hope you understand)

Comment: Need one more example webkit-transform and webkit-transition example

Comment: CSS3 transitions are effects that let an element gradually change from one style to another, 
A transform is an effect that lets an element change shape, size and position.
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp (Hope you understood)